Passing instance-tied method to list foreach
Compare the following uses of ForEach to grow a bounding box from the contained points (Unity, but that's immaterial). One works, the other compiles fine but fails.
Good - explicit lambda:
Bounds ret = new(center, Vector3.zero);
endPositions.ForEach(pos => ret.Encapsulate(pos)); // endPositions is List<Vector3>
return ret;

Bad - passing a method group (I think):
Bounds ret = new(center, Vector3.zero);
endPositions.ForEach(ret.Encapsulate);
return ret;

I would expect the second one to do the same as the first, as it refers to a method on an instance. But it just silently leaves ret as it was. The one difference I see is that on the second form, the parameter to ForEach is a method group rather than a specific overload.
The overload resolution set is this:
public void Encapsulate(Vector3 point);
public void Encapsulate(Bounds bounds);

However, from the definition of List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>) I would expect that only the 1st method, accepting Vector3, would be suitable. However, it seems like the second one (accepting Bounds) is chosen instead.
My only theory is that it has to do with how and where the this parameter is bound, but that's where I'm stuck. What, exactly, is going on here?

Can you share a sample definition of your Vector3 and Bounds classes? Do they participate in any inheritance or have any conversion operators?

Oh, I see now both of those are actually native Unity classes... nevermind then.

@julealgon: Bounds + Vector3

To be clear, List<T>.ForEach is not LINQ, so I've removed the tag. With LINQ, you would expect not to have side effects, but here you have a side effect: you're mutating ret.

@madreflection yes, sorry. I actually edited the title but forgot about the tag. Thanks.

This is such an interesting problem. I went ahead and created a sample that highlights the difference here. Turns out, what you are seeing is due to the fact that Bounds is a value-type. It has nothing to do with the 2 different overloads with Bounds and Vector3.
Take a look at this sample code:
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3];

var myStruct = new MyStruct();
numbers.ForEach(myStruct.Accumulate);
Console.WriteLine($"Method group struct sum: {myStruct.Sum}");

var myStruct2 = new MyStruct();
numbers.ForEach(number => myStruct2.Accumulate(number));
Console.WriteLine($"Lambda struct sum: {myStruct2.Sum}");

var myClass = new MyClass();
numbers.ForEach(myClass.Accumulate);
Console.WriteLine($"Method group class sum: {myClass.Sum}");

var myClass2 = new MyClass();
numbers.ForEach(number => myClass2.Accumulate(number));
Console.WriteLine($"Lambda class sum: {myClass2.Sum}");

public struct MyStruct
{
    public int Sum;

    public void Accumulate(int value) => this.Sum += value;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Sum;

    public void Accumulate(int value) => this.Sum += value;
}

The results are as follows:

Method group struct sum: 0
Lambda struct sum: 6
Method group class sum: 6
Lambda class sum: 6

When the instance is a struct, there is a difference between passing the call as a method group vs a direct lambda, whereas when using a class it works the same. Apparently, when passing via method group, the struct is passed by value so it is copied and you don't get the aggregated results as they were aggregated in a separate copied instance. When you pass it via a lambda, the lambda captures the instance by reference (probably boxing it) and you do get the updated results back.
Obviously, when using a class none of this applies, since it is always passed by reference.
What puzzles me the most in this though is that Visual Studio actually suggests passing via method group in all cases:

So there is a static analysis bug right there... they are definitely not the same.
I didn't know of this difference between method group vs lambda when using value types myself so this was an interesting exercise.
Looks like you should keep the lambda approach for your use case there.
EDIT:
Confirmed. The IDE0200 suggestion above is a known bug and is documented here:

roslyn - IDE0200 doesn't account for mutable structs #66950


You can see how the lambda captures the variable in SharpLab.io. I removed the Console output to keep the code simple.
